# C - Counting number of same elements in 2 arrays

Tags: c, arrays, compare

Let's say we have 2 arrays:

```
char arr1[1024]="ABDDDABAC";
char arr2[1024]="DDDABKDDJABAJJ";
```

and would like to determine the position at which arr2 has the maximum number of matching elements as arr1. For example if arr1[0] is compared to arr2[2], it would result in 5 matches as the code shows below.

```
int matches=0;
for (int i=0;i<strlen(arr2);i++){
    if (arr1[i+2]==arr2[i]){
        matches++;
    }
}
printf("matches: %d\n", matches);
```

The code above returns the number of matches when arr1 is shifted by 2 indices, but does not calculate the number of matches at every single possible shift, and returns the shift which results in the maximum number of matching elements.

Comment: (1) You're indexing past the end of `arr1` if `arr2` is longer (2) You're calculating the length of `arr2` *every* time through the loop, turning an O(n) loop into an O(n**2) loop (major points off for that).  You could calculate *both* lengths up front, then take the minimum.  Or you could forget about the lengths and check for `'\0'` in *both* arrays inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the comparisons in

```
for (int i=0;i<strlen(arr2);i++){
    if (arr1[i+2]==arr2[i]){
        matches++;
    }
}
```

only considers (in an expensive way) the length of *arr2*, there is no protection concerning *arr1* and you can go out of it with an undefined behavior

If you want to find the max number of matches you just have to iterate on the possible offsets in *arr1* and save the best case, for instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  const char * arr1 = "ABDDDABAC";
  const char * arr2 = "DDDABKDDJABAJJ";
  size_t max = 0;
  const char * pmax;
  size_t ln1 = strlen(arr1);
  size_t ln2 = strlen(arr2);

  for (const char * a1 = arr1; *a1 ; ++a1) {
    size_t mx = 0;
    const char * p1 = a1;
    const char * p2 = arr2;

    while (*p1 && *p2) {
      if (*p1++ == *p2++)
        mx += 1;
    }

    printf("%d matches at offset %d\n",mx,  a1 - arr1);

    if (mx > max) {
      max = mx;
      pmax = a1;
      if (mx == ln2)
        /* useless to continue, cannot be better */
        break;
    }

    if (--ln1 < max)
      /* useless to continue, cannot be better */
      break;
  }

  if (max == 0)
    puts("no match");
  else
    printf("max matches %d at offset %d\n", max, pmax - arr1);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 matches at offset 0
2 matches at offset 1
5 matches at offset 2
2 matches at offset 3
2 matches at offset 4
max matches 5 at offset 2
```

Execution under *valgrind*

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==10912== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10912== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10912== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10912== Command: ./a.out
==10912== 
1 matches at offset 0
2 matches at offset 1
5 matches at offset 2
2 matches at offset 3
2 matches at offset 4
max matches 5 at offset 2
==10912== 
==10912== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10912==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10912==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==10912== 
==10912== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10912== 
==10912== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10912== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Note :

- the code makes no supposition concerning the size of the arrays, this is why it contains `if (--ln1 < max) ...` which is never true with the used strings, so *arr1* and *arr2* can be *argv[1]* and *argv[2]* rather than hard coded
- if you want all the number of matches remove all the code concerning *ln1* and *ln2*

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. Please, can you explain what ```for (const char * a1 = arr1; *a1 ; ++a1)``` does?

Comment: @leftail it just iterates all over _arr1_, _a1_ is a pointer in _arr1_, and I use _const_  to indicate I do not modify the string through that pointer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# solution. I can post a C version when I get home, but the logic should be the same.

```
int matches = 0;
int maxMatches = 0;
int maxIndex = 0;

String[] arr1 = { "A", "B", "D", "D", "D", "A", "B", "A", "C" };
String[] arr2 = { "D", "D", "D", "A", "B", "K", "D", "D", "J", "A", "B", "A", "J", "J" };


for (int i = 0; i <= Math.Abs(arr1.Length - arr2.Length); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Math.Min(arr1.Length, arr2.Length); j++)
    {
        if ((i+j) < Math.Min(arr1.Length, arr2.Length)  &&  arr1[i + j] == arr2[j])
        {
            matches++;
        }
    }
    if(matches > maxMatches)
    {
        maxMatches = matches;
        maxIndex = i;
    }

    matches = 0;
}
Console.WriteLine("\nMaximum Matches: " + maxMatches.ToString() + " at index: " + maxIndex.ToString());
Console.Read();
```